# Where is Ember data's BasicAdapter?

Tags: ember-data

In the [readme](https://github.com/emberjs/data/tree/6afa5136dc7221d6256b443b0ebc722e2254c328) of Ember Data, it says: `two core Adapters are provided: the RESTAdapter and BasicAdapter.` but in [Ember Data adapters](https://github.com/emberjs/data/tree/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters) there are only Fixture Adapter and REST Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

The BasicAdapter [has been removed](https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/c1ba443e27e6b0f1db0c174d1cc4f9b18690b56d) for reasons described [here](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/05/03/ember-data-progress-update.html). The main readme needs to be updated.